# How do I add version information to the compiled EXE file in Visual Studio?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2013

I have a C++ console application, and I would like to add a version number to the EXE file. Even better would be if this version would auto increment with every build. Is this somehow possible in Visual Studio 2013?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first part is simple.  Right-click the Resource Files folder in your solution, Add, Resource, Version.  Just edit the fields as you want them.  The editor is not available in the Express edition afaik.

Second part, no, auto-incrementing versions is not simple.  There is build automation tooling for that, the kind you use on a build server.  You wouldn't have asked this question if you use one.